# Cube poem puzzle

Tags: poetry

My friend uploaded this to her page, and I have been watching it for some time now and can not crack it. Maybe there is nothing but I am not sure. 
First letters are spell (OSVIA) which is a twitter account and spacing is also weird. On each line it is 19 19 18 19 and 18 letters but I don't know, I am new to this stuff. I have read about steganography and atbash but have no clue.

Please help

[image]

Comment: As far as the spacing it looks like they just aligned the text in justified style so that it created a square of text

Comment: The account you mention is a private one. @gabbo1092 has already pointed out that the spacing is really not that weird. And it occurs to me that the first letter of each line might be capitalised because someone has hit carriage return and their word processor has auto-capitalised what it thinks is the start of a new sentence! Is there a possibility this might not even be a puzzle?

Comment: @gabbo1092 Thanks for edit, English is not my first language and sometimes i really forget basics.

Comment: @Astralbee it should be, i can't be sure but i asked this question so that maybe trained eye could pick up some clues.

Comment: This seems to be printed on paper. Was there, by any chance, an accompanying Rubik's cube presented with it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't allow ongoing competitions.